# Apex Trigger to create Opportunity Contact Role based on Contact Lookup field

Tags: apex, trigger, force.com, opportunitycontactrole

I have created the following Apex trigger that will create, update and delete Opportunity Contact Roles based on a Contact Lookup field placed on the Opportunity. Everything works great currently.

I am just trying to figure out one final scenario. If John Doe already has a Contact Role but is not the Primary Contact Role and I want him to be. I want to be able to change my look up field to him and then have that check him as the primary.

Currently it just creates a new one and checks them both as primary. So what I need to do is check the current Contact Roles and if there is already one with the same name as in the Lookup field then just check that one as primary, but if there isn't then create a new one.

Below is the code. Please let me know if you need further description.

Thanks,

```
trigger CreateContactRole on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {

List<OpportunityContactRole> newContactRoleList = new List<OpportunityContactRole>();
List<OpportunityContactRole> oldContactRoleList = new List<OpportunityContactRole>();
Set<Id> OppId = new Set<Id>();
sET<Id> ContactId = new Set<Id>();

if(Trigger.isInsert) {
    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
      if(opp.Primary_Contact__c != null) {
          //Creating new Contact Role
          newContactRoleList.add(new OpportunityContactRole(ContactId=opp.Primary_Contact__c,OpportunityId=opp.Id,Role='Decision Maker',IsPrimary=true));
      }
  }
}

if(Trigger.isUpdate) {      
  for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
      if(opp.Primary_Contact__c != null && Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Primary_Contact__c == null) {
            //Creating new Contact Role
          newContactRoleList.add(new OpportunityContactRole(ContactId=opp.Primary_Contact__c,OpportunityId=opp.Id,Role='Decision Maker',IsPrimary=true));
      }
        else if(opp.Primary_Contact__c != null && Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Primary_Contact__c != null) {
            //Create New Contact Role make new CR Primary over the old CR
            Opportunity OldOpp = Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id);
            OppId.add(OldOpp.id);
            ContactId.add(OldOpp.Primary_Contact__c);
            newContactRoleList.add(new OpportunityContactRole(ContactId=opp.Primary_Contact__c,OpportunityId=opp.Id,Role='Decision Maker',IsPrimary=true));
        }
      else if(opp.Primary_Contact__c == null && Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Primary_Contact__c != null) {
            Opportunity OldOpp = Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id);
            OppId.add(OldOpp.id);
            ContactId.add(OldOpp.Primary_Contact__c);
            try {
            //Deleting old Contact Roles
            if(oldContactRoleList.size()>0) delete oldContactRoleList;
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.debug(e);
                trigger.new[0].addError('An error has occurred. Please contact your system administrator.');
            }
      }
  }
}

try {
    //inserting new contact roles
    if(newContactRoleList.size()>0)insert newContactRoleList;

    //Selecting old Contact Roles
    if(OppId.size()>0) oldContactRoleList = [Select Id from OpportunityContactRole where ContactId in : ContactId and OpportunityId in : OppId];        

}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.debug(e);
    trigger.new[0].addError('An error has occurred. Please contact your system administrator.');
}
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming an insert is where there's never been a previous OCR? And an update is where there has been one and you want to change it? Is that how you've structured your code?

Comment: An insert is when the Opportunity itself is created with the "Primary Contact" field populated to go ahead and add that contact as the OCR. And an update there may or may not be OCR already created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some modifications to your trigger that should point you in the right direction. Basically you want to use maps to do what you attempting. Your code was a bit unclear around your delete method. You don't want to do that inside your for loop one record at a time. Collect them all and do it all in a single operation.

If you want to do error handling, adjust the code to get DML save results and use your maps to equate them to the proper opportunity. Be sure to do the Delete operation FIRST since you don't want to have two primary OCR's on the same Opp record!

```
map<Id,Id>OpOldOcR = new map<Id,Id>();
map<Id,Id>OpNewOcR = new map<Id,Id>();

if(Trigger.isUpdate) {

  for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
      if(opp.Primary_Contact__c != null && Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Primary_Contact__c == null) {
            //Creating new Contact Role
          OpNewOcR.put(opp.Id,opp.Primary_Contact__c);
      }
        else if(opp.Primary_Contact__c != null && Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Primary_Contact__c != null) {
            //Create New Contact Role make new CR Primary over the old CR
            OpNewOcR.put(opp.Id,opp.Primary_Contact__c);
            OpOldOcR.put(opp.Id,Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Primary_Contact__c)

        }
      else if(opp.Primary_Contact__c == null && Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Primary_Contact__c != null) {
            OpOldOcR.put(opp.Id,Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Primary_Contact__c)
      }
  }

for(Id oId:OpNewOcR.keyset())
{
      newContactRoleList.add(new OpportunityContactRole(ContactId=OpNewOcR.get(oId),OpportunityId=oId,Role='Decision Maker',IsPrimary=true));
}

CtctIds.addALL(OpOldOcR.values());
list<OpportunityContactRole>toDelete = [SELECT Id, ContactId FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE ContactId IN : CtctIds];

}

if(!toDelete.isEmpty()) delete toDelete;

if(!newContactRoleList.isEmpty()) insert newContactRoleList; 

}
```

Comment: You are using a variable in this "CtctIds" but you never create this. Is this a list?

Comment: Apologies. That was to replace your set<Id> named `ContactId`. I don't like to use variable names that can be confused with API names in my code.

Comment: Ah alright. That makes sense.

Comment: Now I am getting a - Variable does not exist: toDelete

Comment: Look and see in your code whether it was declared within an If statement. If so, move it to the front of your trigger.

Comment: I don't see it being declared anywhere. How would I declare this?

Comment: Its declared as part of the query to collect the OCRs to delete.  `list<OpportunityContactRole>toDelete = new list<OpportunityContactRole>();`. Then just change your query line to begin with `toDelete = [SELECT ...`

Comment: I guess I am not following, I am receiving the error at the line you wrote above:

if(!toDelete.isEmpty()) delete toDelete;

Comment: crmprogdev, I just tested this again and it is still not functioning properly. I added a OCR named John Doe and set them as a business user, then I added John Doe to the Opp as the Primary Contact and it added a second OCR instead of removing the first one and then adding a new one.

Comment: Also, lets say Jane Doe is currently the Primary Contact, and I want to switch it to John Doe, then I do not want Jane to get deleted, I just want Jane to be unchecked as the Primary and John to be added. Currently it deletes Jane and adds John.

Comment: If you don't want them deleted, you need to change `IsPrimary` to `false` and do an update on the OCR's. You'll need to change your logic flow in the trigger for that to happen. You can also add checkbox fields to use to control the behavior your users desire to see when they make a change. Issue with checkboxes is that they're only good for changing one contact at a time & can be difficult to interpret. Good luck!

Comment: Alright. I got that issue handled. One final thing is that I am still having the original issue. The duplication of the OCR is still an issue if the Contact already has an OCR but is not the Primary and is then added as a Primary it adds a second OCR for that Contact and then checks both as Primary. It should delete the first and then add one. I set up the following query to add it to the toDelete list, but it is not working. toDelete = [SELECT Id, ContactId FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE ContactId IN : ConId];

Comment: If that's happening, you need to run a query on all of your OCR's for each opp before you insert them to see if they already exist `WHERE IsPrimary = false`. Compare it with your contactIds and if you find a result, you'll want to delete that OCR before doing your insert of new OCR's.